# Pandas Replace 1st Result in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df4

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Q':['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'Apple', 'orange'], 'R':['a.txt', 'a.txt', 'a.txt', 'b.txt', 'b.txt']})

>>> df4



        Q      R
0   apple  a.txt
1   apple  a.txt
2  orange  a.txt
3   Apple  b.txt
4  orange  b.txt
```

What I would like to output is this:

```
            Q      R
0   breakfast  a.txt
1       apple  a.txt
2      orange  a.txt
3   breakfast  b.txt
4      orange  b.txt
```

In other words, case insensitive, I want to search every row in a dataframe, find the first occurrence of certain words (in this case, that word is apple), and replace it with another word.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a vectorised solution with `groupby` and `idxmin`:

```
v = df.Q.str.lower().eq('apple')    
v2 = (~v).cumsum().where(v)
df.loc[v2.groupby(v2).idxmin().values, 'Q'] = 'breakfast'

df
           Q      R
0  breakfast  a.txt
1      apple  a.txt
2     orange  a.txt
3  breakfast  b.txt
4     orange  b.txt
```

Comment: This is perfect, instead of ".eq" apple, which I assume means "equals apple", I wonder if there is a way to use regex to say "contains apple"

Comment: @LunchBox Change eq to str.contains?

Comment: That did not work, that was the first thing I tried :(

Comment: "Series object has no attribute contains"

Comment: This is perfect if I could make it work with contains

Comment: hmmm . . . maybe instead of looking at it as a series, we look at it as a dataframe and look at that column?

Comment: I tried to use ".isin" but I got an error message about list-like objects are only allowed and I passed a str

Comment: @LunchBox did you try df["mycol"].str.contains? If not, something is wrong

Comment: @LunchBox Why the unaccept? This answers your question as originally formulated, no? I try to help when I can, but I am not always free to help out on SO. If you needed urgent help, the easiest way would be to ask another question. Or else, if you can afford to wait, please be patient, because I do my best to respond to all follow ups.

Comment: I thought it was bad form to change the question and still have this marked as solved. I am appreciative of the help, no offense to you intended :) I'll remark because you did solve my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just really wanted to answer this question.

```
def swap_first(s):
  swap = 1
  luk4 = {'apple'}
  for x in s:
    if x.lower() in luk4 and swap:
      yield 'breakfast'
      swap ^= 1
    else:
      yield x
      if x not in luk4:
        swap ^= 1

df4.assign(Q=[*swap_first(df4.Q)])

           Q      R
0  breakfast  a.txt
1      apple  a.txt
2     orange  a.txt
3  breakfast  b.txt
4     orange  b.txt
```